# Grouping Variables into Subscales in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataset consisting of a number of Likert responses, and I'd like to group them into subscales so I can get descriptive statistics for each subscale. How could I accomplish this in R? For example, with the table below, I'd like to make a group consisting of Q1, Q3, and Q4 data, then another consisting of Q2 and Q5 data, and one more consisting of Q6, Q7, and Q8 data, so that I can call R functions on each group.

```
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Participant | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 | Q7 | Q8 |
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|           1 |  3 |  4 |  4 |  3 |  4 |  3 |  3 |  4 |
|           2 |  4 |  4 |  5 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  5 |
|           3 |  4 |  4 |  5 |  4 |  3 |  5 |  2 |  4 |
|           4 |  4 |  5 |  4 |  3 |  5 |  2 |  3 |  3 |
+-------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the columns you want, with all rows, like this (assuming you have your data frame in `data`):

```
data[, c("Q1", "Q3", "Q4")]
data[, c("Q2", "Q5")]
data[, c("Q6", "Q7", "Q8")]
```

To take a mean over all values in each data set, regardless of column, you can flatten them first with `unlist`:

```
mean(unlist(data[, c("Q1", "Q3", "Q4")]))
mean(unlist(data[, c("Q2", "Q5")]))
mean(unlist(data[, c("Q6", "Q7", "Q8")]))
```

Comment: Hi vlumi, when I use this, e.g. `sapply(data[, c("Q1", "Q3", "Q4")], mean, na.rm=TRUE)`, I'm still getting three seperate means. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to flatten each subset into a vector, for which you can then do a plain `mean`. I added this to the answer.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting `NA` when I run the flattened columns through `mean`.

Comment: You can add the `na.rm = TRUE` as an argument to `mean`, too: `mean(unlist(data[, c("Q1", "Q3", "Q4")]), na.rm = TRUE)`